# Need help, I do not understand why following code is not getting compiled

Tags: c++, stl

Header file is "graph.h"

```
#ifndef _GRAPH_H_
#define _GRAPH_H_

#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class VERTEX
{
public:
    VERTEX(T inVertex): m_vertex(inVertex), m_visited(false){}
    ~VERTEX(){}
private:
    T m_vertex;
    bool m_visited;
};

template <class T>
class GRAPH
{
public:
    GRAPH() {}
    ~GRAPH(){}
    typedef VERTEX<T> GRAPHVERTEX;
    typedef vector<GRAPHVERTEX> ADJLIST;
    typedef map<GRAPHVERTEX, ADJLIST> GRAPHMAP;

    void insert(GRAPHVERTEX inSRC, GRAPHVERTEX inDST)
    {
        GRAPHMAP::iterator itr = m_graph.find(inSRC);
    }

private:
    GRAPHMAP m_graph;
};

#endif
```

And test file is

```
#include "graph.h"

int main( int argc, char**argv)
{
    GRAPH<int> *G = new GRAPH<int>();
    G->insert(VERTEX<int>(0), VERTEX<int>(2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the error when you go to compile?

Comment: I do not know how to paste the error as it is crossing limits

Comment: error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'const VERTEX<T>'

Comment: Congrats for pasting the error!

Comment: By the way, `_GRAPH_H_` is a reserved name; you should remove the `_` from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems.

First you have to qualify the dependent type in `insert`:

```
void insert(GRAPHVERTEX inSRC, GRAPHVERTEX inDST)
{
    typename GRAPHMAP::iterator itr = m_graph.find(inSRC);
}
```

Second, you need a < operator for your vertex class. In the public section of VERTEX add this:

```
bool operator<(const VERTEX<T>& right) const { return m_vertex < right.m_vertex; }
```

As a matter of style note that in C++ ALL CAPS names are usually reserved for constants. `Vertex` would be a much more normal name for your class. Also note that having `using namespace` in a header can have many undesired and unpredictable results depending on include order and should be completely avoided.

EDIT: At least when I compiled this with g++ the first error I got was regarding GRAPHMAP::iterator. When a compiler sees an identifier that could be treated as a variable or a type, it choose to interpret it as a variable by default, but then at a later point discovered it was actually a type. You tell the compiler that it's really a type by using the `typename` keyword.

The second thing to note is that `map` is an ordered container and as such you need to either pass in a comparison function OR provide a < operator for the key of the `map`. Since `VERTEX` is the map key, I set up an `operator<` so that the objects can be sorted and have an order maintained. You may need to adjust the comparison operator as your `VERTEX` class evolves.

Comment: Thanks , it worked, Can you please also explain the code change.

Comment: RE ALLCAPS: But isn't a template just a fancy macro? ;)

Comment: In my mind a template is much more like a normal class than like a macro or constant.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a map with GRAPHVERTEX as a key because you need to be able to *compare* the key with operator <. So you must define this operator.

Answer (score 0):

Your VERTEX class is used as a key in the map;  it is required to have a "less" operator defined.

Answer (score 0):

To use a class as the key in a map, you have to either define `operator<` for that type, or else you need to specify a comparator when you create the map. Assuming objects of that type have a "natural" order, you normally want to use that to implement `operator<`. You typically use a separate comparator object when you need to arrange objects of a given type in a number of different orders, and no one order is really more "natural" or dominant than the others (e.g., when working with employees, you might look at them about equally often by social security number, name, and seniority).